# RPi 3 pybluez connetion timeout

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, bluez, pybluez

On a Raspberry Pi 3, is there a way to set a timeout to `bluetoothsocket.accept` so that it will continue if there was no connection attempted instead of ending the code?

I've tried `settimeout` but it ends the code.